# Long running operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I am running this code which is used in a tableview, so it repeatedly gets called. I have noticed that alot of memory is being taking up at the BOOL isExpanded = [ ......
 How can I improve this?

```
 - (NSIndexPath *)correspondingIndexPathForSubRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSInteger row = 0;
    NSInteger subrow = 0;

    while (1) {

        NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath = [self correspondingIndexPathForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:indexPath.section]];
        BOOL isExpanded = [[self.expandableCells allKeys] containsObject:tempIndexPath] ? [[self.expandableCells objectForKey:tempIndexPath] boolValue] : NO;

        if (isExpanded) {

            NSInteger numberOfExpandedRows = [_SKSTableViewDelegate tableView:self numberOfSubRowsAtIndexPath:tempIndexPath];

            if ((indexPath.row - index) <= numberOfExpandedRows) {
                subrow = indexPath.row - index;
                break;
            }

            index += (numberOfExpandedRows + 1);

        } else
            index++;

        row++;
    }

    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForSubRow:subrow inRow:row inSection:indexPath.section];
}
```

Comment: What's your proof that there is really any problem?

Comment: (By the way, that code is sort of nuts. `while(1)` is an invitation to hang forever. Why aren't you using a `for` loop here?)

Comment: (Or perhaps just use better record-keeping so that the answer to the question you're asking in that loop is available instantly.)

Comment: Lots of things wrong.  Presumably expandableCells is a dictionary, and you do `allKeys` on that, then `containsObject` on the resulting array, vs simply doing `valueForKey`.  That's designed to run slowly!!

Comment: And this whole mess is *recursive*???

Comment: I think that you have a more fundamental problem with the way your data is being stored.  Simply adding some properties to your object classes to store the relationships may avoid all of this "searching" you are doing.  But as @HotLicks said, you an use `valueForKey` instead of the `allKeys` stuff.  And while (1) is a big red flag

Comment: It should be noted that not only is it recursive but the recursion will inevitably occur on entry to the method, meaning you will inevitably have "infinite recursion".